# Redis INCR concurrency

Tags: concurrency, redis, block, blocking

I am using Redis' `INCR` to generate an ID for objects. And then use `ZADD` to add the object using the ID as key.

Do I need to worry about if there are multiple connections executing this same block of code? Say after `id:12` if two connections connect at the same time and both add object using `id:13`, then one of them would be lost.

Answer (score 11):

Since redis is single threaded, this can never happen - only one client can make a change to the database at a time.

Answer (score 7):

As Jonatan Hedborg stated, Redis is single threaded so you never need to worry about two clients doing something at the same time. If, on the other hand, your worry is that you want to run the INCR and ZADD commands sequentially, and want to make sure no other commands are run in between them, you can use [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions), and be guaranteed your commands are run as a single unit with nothing in between.