# Redis INCR and multi processes?

Tags: redis

I used to use PostgreSQL sequence `SELECT nextval('number');` to make sure I get a new number even if there are several clients since `nextval` is guaranteed to return distinct and increasing values.

I wanted to use the same mechanism with Redis.
I thought using the `INCR` command but I want to make sure I well understand that it will give the same guarantee than the `nextval` command?
There is no risk of getting the same number when several processes run this command or do I have to use a Redis lock?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redis INCR concurrency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672355/redis-incr-concurrency)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Redis is a single-threaded engine, so the execution of all commands is serialized. It always provides atomicity and isolation (in the sense of ACID) for each individual command.

The consequence is applying a single INCR command and exploiting its result is safe (even if multiple connections do it concurrently).

Comment: Thanks. Based on this, I added a new question that is related to using INCR but for having a daily counter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443804/redis-reset-counter-every-day