# redis: reset counter every day

Tags: python, lua, redis

I am looking to reset a counter every day using Redis. I am new to Redis so I want to make sure I well understood how transactions and pipes work.

Does the following code ensure that I will always get a unique couple of (date, number) while working in a multi processes environment or do I need to use a Redis lock?

```
import datetime
import redis

r = redis.Redis(...)

def get_utc_date_now():
    return datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()

def get_daily_counter(r, dt_key='dt', counter_key='counter'):

    def incr_daily_number(pipe):
        dt_now = get_utc_date_now().isoformat()  # e.g.: "2014-10-18"
        dt = pipe.get(dt_key)    
        pipe.multi()    
        if dt != dt_now:
            pipe.set(dt_key, dt_now)
            pipe.set(counter_key, 0)
        pipe.get(dt_key)
        pipe.incr(counter_key)

    result = r.transaction(incr_daily_number, dt_key)
    return result[-2:]

# Get the (dt, number) couple
# 2014-10-18, 1
# 2014-10-18, 2
# etc.
dt, number = get_daily_counter(r)
```

### UPDATE

Try with LUA Script:

```
r = redis.Redis(...)

incr_with_reset_on_change_lua_script = """

local dt = redis.call('GET', KEYS[2])
if dt ~= ARGV[2] then
  redis.call('MSET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], KEYS[2], ARGV[2])
end
return redis.call('INCR', KEYS[1])

"""
# Incr KEYS1 but reset first if KEYS2 has changed.
incr_with_reset_on_change = r.register_script(incr_with_reset_on_change_lua_script)

counter_key = 'dcounterA'
watch_key = 'dcounterA_dt'
watch_value = get_utc_date_now().isoformat()

number = incr_with_reset_on_change(keys=[counter_key, watch_key], args=[reset_value, watch_value])
```

Comment: just a curious question, you have embedded the script directly into python string,isnt there a way to say supply a file to register?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider two concurrent transactions occuring at midnight. Both can execute get(dt_key), but one will execute the MULTI/EXEC block first. It will reset the counter, set the new date, increment the counter. The second one will enter also in its MULTI/EXEC block, but because the value of 'dt' has changed, the execution will fail, and incr_daily_number will be called again. This time get(dt_key) will return the new date, so when the MULTI/EXEC block will be executed, the counter will be incremented without any reset. The two transactions will return the new date with different counter values.

So, I believe there is no race condition here, and that the (date,number) couples will be unique.

You could also have implemented this using a server-side Lua script (whose execution is always atomic). It is usually more convenient.

Note that actually, there is no such thing as a Redis lock. The locking mechanism available in the API is provided by the Python client - not by the Redis server. If you look at its implementation, you will realize it is also based on SETNX + WATCH/MULTI/EXEC blocks or Lua scripting.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to try with a LUA Script. I think I can set the date outside of the script in this case. I did not have a chance to test it yet. Let me know what you think if you have a moment. Thanks

Comment: The Lua script looks good to me. You could slightly improve it by using MSET to batch the two successive SET. A unique larger Redis command is always more efficient than two smaller ones.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change and also made it more generic. I was able to try it and it works. One more question: a LUA Script is not stored in the redis server correct? I have to register it with every new client to be able to use it?

Comment: On the contrary - by using SCRIPT LOAD and EVALSHA, Redis will store the script (and the compiled bytecode) so you don't have to send the script to the server with every call to it.

Comment: Oh ok, after looking at the python redis library, it seems that this is what the library does when using the ```register_script``` function. https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/a8e9e19d6fab065eee382942baec79d5f3b56bb5/redis/client.py#L2652